# share std::vector using shared memory IPC in linux

Tags: c++11

I am trying to write `std::vector` to shared memory using boost `managed_shared_memory`.

Writing the data is fine. But at the client process side if I try to read the vector data, it leads to a segmentation fault.

Instead of vector I tried writing an array, it is working fine.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: There is absolutely no chance to help you with such a problem without code. In the hope you will be offering clarifications, I offer you a hint: `boost::interprocess::vector<>`.